# Set ReturnURL for sagepay

Tags: php, curl, opayo

I need to integrate sagepay inframe method to my project. I can grab sagepay form to my own page. Though I don't know where I set the return url. So there is showing error like

```
HTTP Status Code:500,
HTTP Status Message:The request was unsuccessful due to an unexpected condition encountered by the server
Error Code:5006,
Error Description:Unable to redirect to Vendor's web site. The Vendor failed to provide a RedirectionURL.
```

Here is my code. Where can I set returnurl in this code?

```
if($_POST['submit']=="submit")
{
//Test authorize url
//$url="https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/authorise.vsp";

//Test purchase url
$url = 'https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspserver-register.vsp';
//Live
//$url = 'https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspserver-register.vsp';
$params = array();
    $params['VPSProtocol'] = '2.23';
    $params['TxType'] = 'PAYMENT';
    $params['Vendor'] = 'vendorname';
    $params['VendorTxCode'] = 'Txn-ab34qcd1';
    $params['Currency'] = 'GBP';
    $params['Amount'] = 50;
    $params['description'] = 'hello test';
    $params['NotificationURL'] = 'http://exapmle.co.uk/payment-return.php';
    $params['BillingSurname'] = 'Bobby';
    $params['BillingFirstnames'] = 'Bobbysfsf';
    $params['BillingAddress1'] = '14 Tottenham Court Road';
    $params['BillingCity'] = 'London';
    $params['BillingPostCode'] = 'W1T 1JY';
    $params['BillingCountry'] = 'GB';
    $params['billingPhone'] = '555 123-4567';
    $params['DeliverySurname'] = '123 Shipping St';
    $params['DeliveryFirstnames'] = 'Shipsville';
    $params['DeliveryAddress1'] = 'London';
    $params['DeliveryCity'] = 'London';
    $params['DeliveryPostCode'] = '54321';
    $params['DeliveryCountry'] = 'GB';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $curlTimeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = explode(chr(10), curl_exec($ch));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";

echo $posturl = $response[5];

$posturlex=explode("L=",$posturl);
print_r($posturlex);
$nexturl = $posturlex[1];  
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="<?=$nexturl?>" id="sageFrame" style="width:100%;height:500px;border:none"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The RedirectURL is provided when acknowledging the Sage Pay response via your NotificationURL.

The Sage Pay Server is expecting "Status=" to be the first characters in the response. If you have any HTML, comments or header code before that, remove it otherwise Sage Pay Server will treat the response as an error and fail the transaction.

Are you sending the following in your acknowlegement to Sage Pays post to your Notification URL and are you getting this far? Status=, RedirectURL=, StatusDetail=

Comment: now i got well flow with your answer..test environment working fine...now my problem is live environment...there is only show the payment information, no card selection option in that page after sent the customer information to sagepay.if you can Please see this image http://www.sendspace.com/file/2dyt7p. how can i solve the problem...?

Comment: If the merchant number on your TEST account is Ecom and MOTO (Mail Order Telephone Order) but the MID on your LIVE account is only MOTO you will get an error confirming the card types not available via your website. Please contact Sage Pay Support 0845 111 4455 to add an Ecommerce merchant number to the vendor account if want to process Ecommerce transactions.

Comment: Hi @kalyan & sage pay support I couldn't quite understand the concept of notificationURL. Is it a page with another set of codes in it, with redirection rules set up?